# MSP430G2101 WDT not triggering

Tags: msp430, texas-instruments, ti-ccstudio

I have an MSP430G2101 and I need to use the Watchdog to trigger an interrupt. The code I am trying to use is the following:

```
#include <msp430.h> 
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned int cycle = 0;
unsigned int pwmred = 1;


void main(void)
{
WDTCTL = WDT_MDLY_0_5;              // WDT as interval timer (period 0,5 ms)
IE1 |= WDTIE;                       // Enable WDT interrupt

P1DIR |= BIT3 + BIT4 + BIT5;


_BIC_SR(GIE);
 while(1)
 {
 }
}

#pragma vector=WDT_VECTOR
__interrupt void watchdog_timer(void)
{
    cycle++;

     if(cycle >= pwmred) {
         P1OUT &= ~BIT3;
     }

     if (cycle >= 255)
     {
         if(pwmred > 0)
             P1OUT |= BIT3;
         cycle = 0;
     }
}
```

The interrupt is not triggering, I am checking using the debugger and it is also not acting as expected. I am using the latest version of code composer studio. Did I forget something important. I would expect the watchdog_timer method being called every 0.5 ms, but that is not working.

Comment: any link to instruction set?

Comment: Did you tried to enable all interrupt? ( __enable_interrupt() )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you disabled global interrupts.

_BIC_SR(GIE);

Is Bit ***Clear*** Special register.

You want

_BIS_SR(GIE);

Bit ***Set*** special register.

Or use __enable_interrupt(); as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to enable the interrupt in your code. You can enable all the interrupt with `__enable_interrupt();` or enable specific interrupt with `_BIS_SR(name_of_interrupt);`

Comment: Specific interrupts cannot be enabled in the SR.